# Are group_vars in ansible not read before any vars_prompt?

Tags: json, ansible

I've defined a file path variable `sys_labels` in Ansible inventory/group_vars/all/vars pointing to a JSON file.

I'm loading this within the `vars` section in a playbook via `lookup('file', sys_labels) | from_json`.

Debugging this in a simple playbook works. But, if I include a `vars_prompt` that uses the JSON data, it fails. Replacing the `sys_labels` variable in the `vars` section with the actual path works, however.
Why is that so?

Works:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    json: "{{ lookup('file', sys_labels) | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ json }}"
```

where `sys_labels` point to a file `labels.json` containing a JSON structure, e.g.,

```json
{ 
  "labels": { 
    "label1":"true",
    "label1":"false",
    "label2":"true",
    "label3":"true" 
  } 
}
```

Adding the `vars_prompt` fails:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    json: "{{ lookup('file', sys_labels) | from_json }}"
  vars_prompt:
    - name: label_choice
      prompt: |
        {% for key in json.labels %}
        {{ loop.index0 }} - {{ key }}={{ json.labels[key] }}
        {% endfor %}
        Choose labels to apply [none]
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ json }}\n\n{{ label_choice }}"
```

The error is

> ERROR! {{ lookup('file', sys_labels) | from_json }}: 'sys_labels' is undefined.

Replacing the above filepath variable `sys_labels` with the actual path works again:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    json: "{{ lookup('file', '/path/to/labels.json') | from_json }}"
  vars_prompt:
    - name: label_choice
      prompt: |
        {% for key in json.labels %}
        {{ loop.index0 }} - {{ key }}={{ json.labels[key] }}
        {% endfor %}
        Choose labels to apply [none]
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ json }}\n\n{{ label_choice }}"
```

This seems strange to me, and it looks like `vars_prompt` runs before global `group_vars` are eval'd?

And if so, why does `vars_prompt` then still look at the `vars` section of the playbook, but doesn't acknowledge the mapping from within `group_vars`?

Any pointers appreciated.

I'm on ansible core 2.12.1, python 3.10.1, jinja 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is indeed the expected behaviour.

From [@bcoca](https://github.com/bcoca), maintainer of Ansible:

> at the time `vars_prompt` runs only extra vars are defined, so the `when` *[the issue on which @bcoca was answering was about a `when` on `vars_prompt`, but it applies the same here -- Ed.]* will not work with host/group vars nor facts.

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13263#issuecomment-159037298*</sup>

What you can do, to come around this issue, is to use the [`pause`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) module instead.

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars: 
    json: "{{ lookup('file', sys_labels) | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - pause: 
        prompt: |-
          {% for key in json.labels %}
          {{ loop.index0 }} - {{ key }}={{ json.labels[key] }}
          {% endfor %}
          Choose labels to apply [none]
      register: label_choice

    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ json }}\n\n{{ label_choice.user_input }}"
```

This yields:

```
TASK [pause] **********************************************************************
[pause]
0 - foo=bar
1 - baz=qux
Choose labels to apply [none]:
foo
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    {'labels': {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'qux'}}
  
    foo
```

Comment: Thank you, @β.εηοιτ.βε. This answered my question perfectly (and also gave me some hints on proper quoting/ marking of questions in general). Cheers!